# How to specify conditons in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, each

How to specify conditions in each function in Rails.

```
@page = 1
@allRecords = #This result will come from API.. It have 500 records.

resultArray = []
@allRecords.each do |t| #need to specify condition here based on @page value
   #processes...
   resultArray << t
end

render :json => resultArray
```

i will send **@page** number to controller. Then **resultArray** will sent final values

```
Input : @page = 1
Output : resultArray = Records 1 - 50

Input : @page = 2
Output : resultArray = Records 51 - 100

Input : @page = 3
Output : resultArray = Records 101 - 150 

like wise...
```

How can i achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@page = 1
@allRecords = #This result will come from API.. It have 500 records.
per_page = 50
resultArray = @allRecords.slice(@page + (@page - 1) * per_page, per_page)
# if result is not Array (Enumerable)
#resultArray = @allRecords.to_a.slice(@page + (@page - 1) * per_page, per_page)
```